# Scala spec2 object.productID must_== "123" fails

Tags: scala, specs2

```
scalaVersion  := "2.10.1"
"org.specs2"          %%  "specs2"        % "1.13" % "test"
```

My spec2 test:

```
package com.mycompany.dataminer.parser

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

case class Product(productID:String)

class SimpleTest  extends Specification {

  "product" should {

    "have id = 123" in {
      var product1 = Product("123")
      product1 must not beNull
      product1.productID must_== "123"

      var product2 = Product("123")
      product2 must not beNull
      product2.productID must_== "123"

      var product3 = Product("123")
      product3 must not beNull
      product3.productID must_== "123"
    }
  }

}
```

Result:

```
scala: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[com.mycompany.dataminer.parser.Product]
      product1.productID must_== "123"
               ^
```

Once I wrote this code, it was working, until I add this lines:

```
product1 must not beNull
product2 must not beNull
product3 must not beNull
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is problem with Scala's expression parsing (semi-column inference) and the way that specs2 models matchers.

The line with the first matcher, `product1 must not beNull` is interpreted as `product1.must(not) beNull`. This means that `beNull` is in the position of a method call without arguments but if it had arguments they would have to be of type `Matcher[Product]`. This is because the whole expression is of type `MatchResult[Product]` and the `MatchResult` trait has an `apply` method.

The consequence is that Scala infers that the arguments to the first line expression are on the second line, `product1.productID` and are of type `String` which is unexpected.

There are 3 workarounds for this situation:

- a newline

  ```
  product1 must not beNull

  product1.productID must_== "123"
  ```
- a semi-column

  ```
  product1 must not beNull;
  product1.productID must_== "123"
  ```
- a parenthetised `not`

  ```
  product1 must not(beNull)

  product1.productID must_== "123"
  ```

This will be mitigated in the next specs2 version by making the `MatchResult[T].apply` method private in order to transform the compilation error to `method apply in trait MatchResult cannot be accessed in org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Product]` and add a description of the potential issue in the Scaladoc on this method.

Comment: I've post this issue to spec2 issue tracker (in order not to forget :) )

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

1. Import name conflict, or
2. something amiss in the Specs

Perhaps the following Acceptance Test example might provide a clue:

```
 import org.specs2.Specification
 import xyz.{Product => TestProduct}  // <- Alias the "Product" package
```

trait MyTestHelper {
   val pId = "123"
   lazy val product = new TestProduct.Product(pId, ...) // <-- Class to test
 }

class MyTest extends Specification with MyTestHelper { def is =
   ("Product should be " + pId) ! product.ProductID must be_==("123") ^ 
   end
 }

Comment: I've provided new description. I guess now it is easy to reproduce.